# filter out divs from body of request url using underscore and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

I need to filter out the return data from url. This data is in html and I only need certain divs with certain ID or class not everything. I am using node module "request" to make request to the url and trying to use underscore module to filter out the unwanted divs or tags. I am not sure if I am taking the right approach. Here is my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
var request = require('request');
var _ = require('underscore');


module.exports = function(website, provinceName, cityName){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
        var encodedCity = encodeURIComponent(cityName);
        var encodedProvince = encodeURIComponent(provinceName);

        var url = website  + provinceName + '/' + cityName;

        // make a request to the url and get the data back
        if(url){
            request({
                url: url
            }, function(error, response, body){
                if(error){
                    reject('Unable to fetch the lawyers' + error);
                }else{
                    // filter out all the data that does not have class=classname or id=idName 
                    var html = _.pick(body, '.classname', 'myidname');
                    //then loop over and only send back the ones with class=classname or id=idName
                    _.each(html, function(){
});
                    resolve(html);
                }
            });
        }else{
            reject();
        }


    });
};
```

Comment: Check out [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get just the text from an HTML element and its children (without the tags but including CDATA) you could try the `textContent` property. See how it works [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).